# How to disallow android studio from auto formatting the whole file when a piece of code is generated and added

Tags: android-studio, coding-style, code-formatting

***EDIT -Andoird studio by default even formats the whole AndroidManifest file while adding the activity that I create using the template.***

I am working on an android app project with multiple people in my team, and many of the files are not formatted as per android studio styles.
When i add code, I only format my own code, so as to keep Git annotate keep clean.
For example - Now I use Add new app widget template and android studio added pieced of code in ANdroidmanifest.xml and style.xml but it also formats the whole file.
[image: adds the last para about app widget from generated, but auto formats above lines as well]

What changes in the preferences should i make to forbid android studio from auto formatting files?